# alguien conoce que hace esto: Fuction[]?

Tags: angular, typescript

alguno hay visto en TypeScript una función como esta `Fuction[]`, no la había visto antes así. entiendo que es un array de funciones. alguien me puede explicar bien como funciona. Gracias.

Este es un ejemplo de donde lo vi. 
`const matchFunctionsToApply: Function[] = Object.keys(this.matches)`
  `.filter(matchKey => this.matches[matchKey].selected)`
  `.map(matchKey => this.matches[matchKey].func);`

Comment: Puedes agregar el código dónde viste eso

Comment: En TS `Fuction[]` se utilizar para definir que un tipo es un array de funciones.

Comment: Simplemente se usa como se usaria cualquier otro array, solo es una coleccion de elementos de tipo `Function`

Comment: osea que ese Fuction[] no es una función sino una interfaz??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Function` es una interfaz que se aplica a todas las funciones. Su descripción únicamente dice `Crea una función`

Por tanto `Function[]` espera un arreglo de funciones. Si pasas un valor que no coincida con la interfaz te dará un error `...missing de following properties...` y si no es una función con las propiedades de la interfaz también te dará un error.

Esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14816623/4326551) comenta algo relacionado:

> The interface ensures that all callers of functions that implement the interface supply the required arguments

.

> ...La interfaz se asegura que todos los llamadores de funciones que implementan la interfaz proporcionen los argumentos requeridos...

De esta manera Typescript nos permite saber que lo que estamos manejando sea una función con todas las propiedades comunes y que no haya problemas en su ejecución al ser código dinámico.

Comment: ahhh okok, pense que la palabra Function era una palabra reservada para Js no? ahora si tiene sentido. para mi. Me encontre con esto cuando el linter de angular me pidio que lo cambiara por un arrow function. y yo quede confundido. Chevre tiene sentido para mi. Gracias.